# SpriteSheet animation in windows phone apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal, sprite-sheet

Is there any library which helps to achieve spritesheet animation in windows apps.
If we animate the sequence of images, there is a glitch. what are the other ways to achieve sprite sheet animation without glitch. Is this possible via unity or directx. I tried googling but couldn't find anything relevant except animating images which is creating glitch.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get that working without glitches. If it happens when you switch sprite sheets - make sure to use at least two `Image` controls to be able to load the next sheet while animating through the first one. The interactive books from Sesame Workshop use XAML-based sprite sheets.